# Adding a fading gradient over image in slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm trying to add a fading gradient over an image in a slideshow, so that, when viewing a certain picture (my slide shows 3 pics, one middle & then a small portion of the first & prev pic), the pictures on the sides will have this gradient over them, so the previous pic on the left will have it's left side fading out, and vice versa. If you get me? Similar to what was commented here: [How do you apply a fading overlay to an image in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991624/how-do-you-apply-a-fading-overlay-to-an-image-in-css) I have 2 `.png's`, one that fades left, one that fades right. Where do I apply these in terms of `HTML` & `.css`? You'll see them at the very bottom of the `.css`, however they are not applied correctly and does not have corresponding divs in html (needed?). When you hover over the next & prev image, they should also lighten up a bit (lose some of their fade-effect). Example: http://www.deadmau5.com

**HTML**

```
<div class="hero">
    <div class="hero-carousel">

        <article>
          <img src="images/deadmau5/slide1.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
          <img src="images/deadmau5/slide2.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
          <img src="images/deadmau5/slide3.jpg" />
        </article>

        <article>
          <img src="images/deadmau5/slide4.jpg" />
        </article>

    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.hero-carousel').heroCarousel({
            easing: 'easeOutExpo',
            css3pieFix: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.hero {
    width: 1366px;
    height: 340px; position:absolute;top:270px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 48px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top:9px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, .15);
    border-bottom: 9px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, .15);
    padding: 0 0 12px 0;
}

.hero-carousel article {
    width: 970px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 470px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.hero-carousel-container article {
    float: left;
}

.hero-carousel article img{
    border-style:solid;border-width:6px;color:#000; position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.hero-carousel article .contents {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 72px;
    left: 48px;
    list-style: none;
    color: #000;
    width: 556px;
    padding: 20px;

    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    -pie-background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);

    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;

    behavior: url(/assets/PIE.htc);
}

.hero-carousel-nav {
    width: 980px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -490px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.hero-carousel-nav li {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 48px;
   right: 48px;
   list-style: none;
}

.hero-carousel-nav li.prev {
    left: -50px;
    right: auto;
    bottom: 100px;
}
.hero-carousel-nav li.next {
    right: -30px;
    left: auto;
    bottom: 100px;
}

.hero-carousel-nav li a {     
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #D21034; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.hero-carousel-nav li.next a { 
    background: url('../images/deadmau5/large-arrow-right.png'),
                -5px -7px no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 105px;        /*width of your img*/
    height: 105px;      /*height of your img*/
    font-size: 0px; 
    right: -15px;  /*this is better than 1px*/
    bottom: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    outline:none;
}

.hero-carousel-nav li.prev a { 
    background: url('../images/deadmau5/large-arrow-left.png'),
                -7px -7px no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 105px;        /*width of your img*/
    height: 105px;      /*height of your img*/
    font-size: 0px;    /*this is better than 1px*/
    left: -50px;
    bottom: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: If you look at the [style sheet](http://www.deadmau5.com/wp-content/themes/deadmau5/css/style.css) around line 250 is what you're wanting. They've used `position` and `z-index` to overlay the fader elements and on hover, they set the `opacity` to a less than 1 decimal.

Comment: I'm not very experienced, may you post some `code` to illustrate? And please keep it extremly simple for the same reason, haha.

Comment: Like, I'm also trying to replicate the thing that makes the arrows "glow" when hovered over, to no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to handle this, but this is a simplistic example of how this site is laying everything out.

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 504px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#slide-container {
    width: auto;
}

.article {
    display: inline-block;
}

.article img {
    width: 165px;
    height: auto;    
}

#overlay-left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 165px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url('http://www.deadmau5.com/wp-content/themes/deadmau5/images/slider-fade-left.png') no-repeat top left;
    z-index: 2;
}

#overlay-right {
    position: absolute;
    width: 165px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url('http://www.deadmau5.com/wp-content/themes/deadmau5/images/slider-fade-right.png') no-repeat top right;
    z-index: 2;
}

#overlay-left:hover, #overlay-right:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="slide-container">
        <div class="article">
            <a href="">
                <img src="http://www.deadmau5.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/slide1.jpg" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="article">
            <a href="">
                <img src="http://www.deadmau5.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/slide1.jpg" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="article">
            <a href="">
                <img src="http://www.deadmau5.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/slide1.jpg" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay-left"></div>
    <div id="overlay-right"></div>
</div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VC956/3/) is a JSFiddle of this if you want to play with it.

Comment: Yes but, how would I implent this with mine? What would I replace the #overlay's with, since the thingy's I'm using are different. Mine are called .heroCarousel or whatever they're called..

Comment: `container` would be `hero` and `slide-container` would be `hero-carousel` in this case. You need to add the `overlay-left` and 'overlay-right` elements after `hero-carousel`.

Comment: Wait what.. I'm really confused. I'm not very good at this, and I'm not sure where to add what to my already excisting `.css` in the question.

Comment: You'll be adding CSS and HTML code. Compare my bare-bones example code and adjust yours. Writing out the complete the solution is beyond the scope of this site as that would be me doing your work for you.

Comment: Okay so, I got them the way I want it. Trouble is, they're too "thick", you don't easily see through them when they're not hovered over. And also, they're on-top of my nav arrows? Well that's 'cause I started this course like a month ago, I am very new to all of this. EDIT: Fixed the opacity issues, all that is now is that it's above my nav-arrows.

Comment: EDIT: Fixed that as well. Everything's fixed.

Comment: I understand being new, but Stackoverflow is to answer questions without getting too case-specific as others might come looking for the same answer. The overlays on top of your nav arrows likely because of the ordering of the elements in your code coupled with the `z-index` setting. Increase the `z-index` in the style rules for your arrows. You can change the `opacity` on the standard style rule or make your own overlay image, but the latter might be beyond you at the moment if you don't have experience with graphic creation.

Comment: Well all I day was just set the z-index on the nav's to 3 and add a new opacity:x.x; to the left & right overlays (when not being hovered on).